# Xcode 10 and Xcode 11 compatability

Tags: app-store, swift4, swift5, xcode11, xcode10

I am a beginner in Xcode.
I don’t have xcode 11 on my mac because it cannot run Mojave (required osx for Xcode 11).

Can I create the app on my computer in Xcode 10, then send the project file to a friend with Xcode 11, and then publish the app to App Store from my friend’s computer? What problems can I expect? Swift 4/5 incompatability? Is there any other solution?

Comment: Borrow your friend’s computer and develop the whole thing there? Get a new computer? These are fiscal / moral issues, not programming matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. If your swift version is 4 it's okay. not a problem.
I think the only thing will happen in your friend's Xcode is a warning that says to you 'Conversion to swift 5 is available'.
But it is okay to ignore it and to publish your application with swift 4